# Get multiple distinct values from query in Entity Framework

Tags: sql, entity-framework, lambda

I'm running a query that will get results based on a location search and date. I have a `geography` column with location points (lat/long) that's indexed. When I search for an event on a date it searches for all events within a distance (radius) on that date.

The problem is that if there are, say 10 events, all at the same location on the same date, all 10 results will come back in the first page. I'd like to mix this up and only show 2-3 from each location to give the result set some variety, so the user doesn't just see all events from one location.

I know I can use distinct to only fetch one event from each location, but how would I use it to get me 2-3 distinct values?

Here is my query so far.

```
viewModel.Events = dbContext.YogaSpaceEvents
                            .Where(i => i.EventDateTime >= adjustedSearchDate &&
                                        i.LocationPoints.Distance(location) <= radius)
                            .Distinct()
                            .OrderBy(i => i.EventDateTime)
                            .Select(i => new EventResult
                                             {
                                                 //fill view model here
                                             })
                            .ToPagedList(Page, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to get EF to generate such a query, which for SQL Server would be something like this:

```
with q as
(
  select *, 
        ( row_number() over (partition by StateProvinceId order by CityID) -1 ) / 3 MyRanking
  from Application.Cities
)
select CityId, CityName,StateProvinceID
from q
order by MyRanking, StateProvinceID, CityID
offset 10 rows
fetch next 20 rows only
```

Note that this example doesn't use distance.  But the idea is identical: the first 3 cities in each state are returned first, then the next 3, etc.

Or you could fetch all the matching events and sort them in memory.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to do something like:

```
dbContext.YogaSpaceEvents
.Where(i => i.EventDateTime >= adjustedSearchDate &&
            i.LocationPoints.Distance(location) <= radius)
.GroupBy(i => i.Geography)
.SelectMany(g => g.OrderBy(x => x.EventDateTime).Take(3))
.Select(i => new EventResult { //fill view model here })
.ToPagedList(Page, 10);
```